# JSP Compilation Difference Between WebLogic 8 and WebLogic 11g (Special Characters)

Tags: jsp, weblogic

We recently upgraded from WebLogic 8 to WebLogic 11g.

We store JSPs in the database as blobs. (Yes, I know this is not good. No, it wasn't me who made the decision to do this.)

Now that we have moved from 8 to 11g, we find that some of the JSPs stored in the database that worked fine under WebLogic 8 do not compile under WebLogic 11.

Specifically it appears that 8 used to ignore special characters in Strings (carriage returns) and 11g has a problem with this.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Is there a difference in the way that JSPs compile between the two versions?